# How to load power bi report in mobile view layout?

Tags: react-native, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I am working on power BI report in react-native it working only for desktop view but not load in mobile layout view.I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-powerbi plugin. I try may any but not finding solution for that so please help me. I am put our code here I show some answer it suggest to change layoutType -2 and also add isMobileView = true in embedded Url but not getting solution. Thanks

var embedConfiguration =
{

```
  type: 'report',
  accessToken: props.embedConfiguration.accessToken,
  embedUrl: props.embedConfiguration.embedUrl,
  id: props.embedConfiguration.id,
  settings: {
    filterPaneEnabled: false,
    navContentPaneEnabled: true,
    layoutType: 2
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To embed a mobile view layout for a Power BI report, you need to create “Mobile Layout” in Power BI Desktop.

For selecting the "Mobile Layout" go to View Panel and then select Mobile Layout.

Once it is created you can use `layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait` to embed in Mobile View.

So the final embed config will look similar to this:

```
var embedConfiguration = {
 type: 'report',
  accessToken: props.embedConfiguration.accessToken,
  embedUrl: props.embedConfiguration.embedUrl,
  id: props.embedConfiguration.id,
  settings: {
    filterPaneEnabled: false,
    navContentPaneEnabled: true,
    layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait,
  }
};
```

**References:**

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/mobile